# Proper structuring of a Laravel application and where responses should be handled?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So at the moment my application is structured such that Controllers will access a "Processor" class for certain objects (Business logic). This processor object then accesses all the relevant repositories necessary to perform the action (Data access logic).

For instance, let's pretend there is a UserProcessor class which we are using to attempt updating the user's email via some function: updateEmail($user_id, $new_email). The validation is then handled on the email, but lets say this validation fails. Obviously there are multiple vectors by which the updateEmail function can fail. Many of these will throw exceptions, but in the case of the validation and a few others, they will not (they aren't totally unexpected errors thus an exception is not proper?).

My problem occurs because of the potential for multiple failures. I'm unsure how to handle updateEmail's non-exception type failures. I could just have updateEmail return a response object as necessary which solves everything. But something about this doesn't feel right, isn't the generation of a response object supposed to be handled in the Controller?

I could also create an errors variable, which the controller accesses on receiving False from updateEmail. But this ends up being very generic in-terms of my api, which returns "status", "message", and "payload". In my current form I have a generic message for errors like: "validation error(s) have occurred." and then in the payload specific errors are listed. I could create a errorMessage variable in my UserProcessor, but at this point I might as well return a response object as I need to also store the HTTP error code?

Am I overthinking this? Should the processor just handle responses?

EDIT:

```
class UserProcessor {

    private $user;

    private $error_code;
    private $error_message;
    private $error_payload;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryContract $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function error(){
        return array(
            'code' => $this->error_code,
            'message' => $this->error_message,
            'payload' => $this->error_payload
        );
    }

    public function updateEmail($user_id, $new_email, $confirmation_email){

        $validator = $this->validateEmail(array(
            'email' => $new_email,
            'email_confirmation' => $confirmation_email
        ));
        if( $validator->fails() ){
            $this->error_code = 400;
            $this->error_message = 'validation error(s) have occurred.';
            $this->error_payload = $validator->errors();
            return False;
        }

        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);

        $returned = $this->user->update($user_id, array(
            'email' => $new_email,
            'confirmed' => 0,
            'confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code
        ));
        if( !$returned ){
            $this->error_code = 500;
            $this->error_message = 'an internal error occurred while ';
            $this->error_message .= 'attempting to update user record.';
            return False;
        }

        $this->sendConfirmationCodeEmail($user_id);

        return True;

    }

}

class UserController extends Controller{

    private $user;
    private $processor;

    public function __construct(UserRepositoryContract $user, UserProcessor $processor){
        $this->middleware('auth.api', [ 'except' => ['verifyEmail', 'updateEmail', 'changeName', 'changePassword', 'deleteAccount'] ]);
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    public function updateEmail(Request $request, $user_id){

        $response = $this->processor->updateEmail($user_id, $request->email, $request->email_confirmation);

        if( !$response ){
            $error = $this->processor->error();
            return $this->responseBuilder(
                'fail',
                $error['code'],
                $error['message'],
                $errors['payload']
            );
        }

        return $this->responseBuilder('success', 200, 'successfully updated user\'s email.');

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is kind of convoluted and broad in some respects. You should include code with your question that showcases the example you're trying to describe. That would give some context and perspective on your current implementation, which as this point is a bit too abstracted by the long explanation.

Comment: @Bogdan sorry for the long response time. I've added the relevant code to the post above. What I'm currently doing is just using an error() function on the processor but something about this just feels clunky and wrong.

Comment: One way of handling this, is to have the `domain model` return a `DTO` [Practical PHP Patterns: Data Transfer Object](https://dzone.com/articles/practical-php/practical-php-patterns-data) which has the result of the validation in it. That ca be examined by the controller. It can then decide what to do with it?

Comment: Hey @RyanVincent thanks for the response. I'm going to take a look at the link you posted.

Comment: The nice thing about them is that they accumulate `state` so you don't have to redo any checks. Also, It can be passed directly to `view` without the controller needing to bother about what the `view` wants? The domain fills in the data for the `requested option` - the `view` gets it and knows how to display it. The controller decides where to route to depending on the status? Imagine a display field gets added to the database table. The controller doesn't change. Just the domain model and the view.